# Verificar se a árvore é AVL ou não

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, árvore

Olá, preciso fazer com que a função **verificaAVL** *(que é chamada no case 8, linha 364)*, **verifique se a árvore é AVL ou não**, ou seja, se o resultado de seus nodos forem -1,0 ou 1, ele apenas escreve na tela: ARVORE INSERIDA É AVL, caso encontre qual quer valor de nodo DIFERENTE dos citados, retornar: NÃO É AVL.

**A função inicia na linha 276, na linha 260 e 246 verás que tentei implementar outra função que verificaria para cada lado da árvore e após retorna para a verificaAVL o seu grau, sem sucesso. *(vai estar comentado incompleto onde precisa ser implementado...)***

Vim tentar aqui, por que estou a dias nisso, já fiz (como podem ver no código) verificar se a arvore é caminhamento pre-fixado, se é caminhamento pós-fixado ou central com muita dificuldade pois sou novato em C e principalmente na questão de implementar o código com recursividade que estou tentando, não há café que chegue mais, estou desesperado, peço ajuda.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



struct Vertice
{
    int chave;
    struct Vertice* esquerdo;
    struct Vertice* direito;
};

int menu()
{
    int op;
    printf("(1)Inserir\n");
    printf("(2)Imprimir\n");
    printf("(3)Excluir folha\n");
    printf("(4)Procurar chave\n");
    printf("(5)Executar caminhamento pre-fixado\n");
    printf("(6)Executar caminhamento pos-fixado\n");
    printf("(7)Executar caminhamento central\n");
    printf("(8)Verificar se a arvore e AVL\n");
    printf("(9)Sair\n");
    printf("Digite uma opcao: ");
    scanf("%d",&op);
    return op;
}

struct Vertice* alocaVertice(int chave)
{
    struct Vertice* novo;
    novo = (struct Vertice*)malloc(sizeof(struct Vertice));/*aloca memoria necessaria para um novo registro*/
    if(novo!=NULL)//se conseguiu alocar
    {
        novo->chave = chave;/*adiciona a chave digitada pelo usuario ao campo chave do novo vertice*/
        novo->esquerdo = NULL;
        novo->direito = NULL;
    }
    return novo;//retorna o endereco de memoria alocado ou NULL se nao conseguir alocar espaco
}


void inserir(struct Vertice** raiz, int chave)
{

    int ok;
    struct Vertice* novo;
    struct Vertice* ptAux;
    novo = alocaVertice(chave);
    if (*raiz == NULL)/*se arvore esta vazia*/
    {
        *raiz = novo;
        printf("RAIZ INICIAL adicionada com sucesso! \n");
        system("pause");
    }

        else
        {
           ptAux = *raiz;
           ok = 0; /*falso*/
           while(!ok)
           {
               if (novo->chave > ptAux->chave)
               {
                   if (ptAux->direito == NULL)
                   {
                       ptAux->direito = novo;
                       ok = 1; /*verdadeiro*/
                       printf("Nodo adicionado com sucesso! \n");
                       system("pause");
                   }
                   else
                    ptAux = ptAux->direito;
               }
               else if (ptAux->esquerdo == NULL)
               {
                   ptAux->esquerdo = novo;
                   ok = 1;
                   printf("Nodo adicionado com sucesso! \n");
                   system("pause");
               }
               else
                ptAux = ptAux->esquerdo;
           }
        }
}

void imprimir(struct Vertice* vertice)
{
    struct Vertice* ptAux;
    ptAux = vertice;
    if (ptAux != NULL)
    {
        printf("Meu endereco = %d ", (int)ptAux);
        printf("Filho Esquerdo = %d ", (int)ptAux->esquerdo);
        printf("Filho Direito = %d ", (int)ptAux->direito);
        printf("Chave = %d ", ptAux->chave);
        printf("\n");
        imprimir(ptAux->esquerdo);//chamada recursiva
        imprimir(ptAux->direito);//chamada recursiva
    }
}

void imprimirPre(struct Vertice* vertice) /* EXECUTA ENCAMINHAMENTO PRE-FIXADO */
{
    struct Vertice* ptAux;
    ptAux = vertice;
    if (ptAux != NULL)
    {
        printf("Meu endereco = %d ", (int)ptAux);
        printf("Filho Esquerdo = %d ", (int)ptAux->esquerdo);
        printf("Filho Direito = %d ", (int)ptAux->direito);
        printf("Chave = %d ", ptAux->chave);
        printf("\n");
        imprimirPre(ptAux->esquerdo);//chamada recursiva
        imprimirPre(ptAux->direito);//chamada recursiva
    }
}

void imprimirPos(struct Vertice* vertice) /* EXECUTA ENCAMINHAMENTO POS-FIXADO */
{
    struct Vertice* ptAux;
    ptAux = vertice;
    if (ptAux != NULL)
    {
        imprimirPos(ptAux->esquerdo);//chamada recursiva
        imprimirPos(ptAux->direito);//chamada recursiva
        printf("Meu endereco = %d ", (int)ptAux);
        printf("Filho Esquerdo = %d ", (int)ptAux->esquerdo);
        printf("Filho Direito = %d ", (int)ptAux->direito);
        printf("Chave = %d ", ptAux->chave);
        printf("\n");// INCOMPLETO

    }
}

void imprimirCentral(struct Vertice* vertice) /* EXECUTA ENCAMINHAMENTO CENTRAL */
{
    struct Vertice* ptAux;
    ptAux = vertice;
    if(ptAux!=NULL)
    {
        imprimirCentral(ptAux->esquerdo);//chamada recursiva
        printf("Meu endereco = %d ", (int)ptAux);
        printf("Filho Esquerdo = %d ", (int)ptAux->esquerdo);
        printf("Filho Direito = %d ", (int)ptAux->direito);
        printf("Chave = %d ", ptAux->chave);
        printf("\n");
        imprimirCentral(ptAux->direito);//chamada recursiva
    }
}

void excluirFolha(struct Vertice** raiz, int chave)
{
        struct Vertice* ptAux;
        struct Vertice* ptAnt;
        ptAux = *raiz;

        if ((*raiz)-> chave == chave)
        {
            if (((*raiz)->esquerdo == NULL) && ((*raiz)->direito == NULL)) // se RAIZ nao houver filhos...
            {
                (*raiz) = NULL;
                printf("CHAVE RAIZ EXCLUIDA COM SUCESSO!");
                system("pause");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Nodo nao e uma folha, erro ao excluir!");
                system("pause");
            }
        }
        else // se nao houver filhos...
        {
            while ((ptAux)->chave != chave && ptAux != NULL)
            {
                ptAnt = ptAux;

                if (chave < (ptAux)->chave)
                {
                    ptAux = ptAux->esquerdo;
                }
                else
                {
                    ptAux = ptAux->direito;
                }
            }
            if(ptAux == NULL)
                printf("\nValor nao encontrado");
            else
            {
                if (((ptAux)->esquerdo == NULL) && ((ptAux)->direito == NULL))
                {
                    free(ptAux);
                    if(chave < ptAnt->chave)
                        ptAnt->esquerdo = NULL;
                    else if(chave > ptAnt->chave)
                        ptAnt->direito = NULL;
                    printf("CHAVE EXCLUIDA COM SUCESSO!");
                    system("pause");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Nodo nao e uma folha, erro ao excluir!");
                    system("pause");
                }
            }
        }
}

void procuraChave(struct Vertice* raiz, int chave)
{
    struct Vertice* ptAux;
    struct Vertice* ptAnt;
    ptAux = raiz;

    while ((ptAux)->chave != chave && ptAux != NULL)
    {
        ptAnt = ptAux;

        if (chave < (ptAux)->chave)
        {
            ptAux = ptAux->esquerdo;
        }
        else
        {
            ptAux = ptAux->direito;
        }
    }

    if(ptAux == NULL)
        printf("\nValor nao encontrado");
    else
    {
        if (ptAux != raiz)
        {
            printf("\nChave do nodo pai: %d\n", ptAnt->chave);
        }
        else
            printf("\nNao e possivel mostrar a chave do nodo pai pois e a raiz\n");
        imprimir(ptAux);
    }
}

int verificaGrauEsq(struct Vertice* ptAux, int grauE) // INCOMPLETO FALTA SE ->ESQUERDO && ->DIREITO !=NULL ENTAO PESQUISAR
{
    int grau;
    do // verifica grau da esquerda
    {
        grau++;
        if(ptAux->esquerdo == NULL)
            ptAux=ptAux->direito;
        else(ptAux->direito == NULL);
            ptAux=ptAux->esquerdo;
    }while(ptAux->esquerdo !=NULL || ptAux->direito !=NULL);
    return grau;
}

int verificaGrauDir(struct Vertice* ptAux, int grauD) // INCOMPLETO
{
    int grau;
    do // verifica grau da esquerda
    {
        grau++;
        if(ptAux->esquerdo == NULL)
            ptAux=ptAux->direito;
        else if(ptAux->direito == NULL)
            ptAux=ptAux->esquerdo;


    }while(ptAux->esquerdo !=NULL || ptAux->direito !=NULL);
    return grau;
}

void verificaAVL(struct Vertice* vertice) // INCOMPLETO
{
    struct Vertice* ptAux;
    struct Vertice* ptRFixo;
    int grauE=1; // variavel grau recebe 1, pq se entrar na função é pq a arvore não é vazia, logo tem pelo menos 1 grau
    int grauD=1; // variavel grau recebe 1, pq se entrar na função é pq a arvore não é vazia, logo tem pelo menos 1 grau
    ptAux = vertice; // atribui a raiz a uma variavel que sofrera alterações.

    grauE = verificaGrauEsq(ptAux->esquerdo, grauE); // INCOMPLETO

    grauD = verificaGrauDir(ptAux->direito, grauD); // INCOMPLETO


}

int main()
{
    int op = 0, chave;
    struct Vertice* ptRaiz = NULL;/*cria um ponteiro para armazenar o endereço da raiz da Arvore*/

    while (op != 9)
    {
        op = menu();
        switch (op)
        {
        case 1:/*inserir vertice*/
            printf("Digite o valor do vertice: ");
            scanf("%d",&chave);
            inserir(&ptRaiz, chave);
            break;

        case 2:/*imprimir*/
            printf("\n");
            if(ptRaiz!=NULL)//se Arvore tem conteudo
                imprimir(ptRaiz);
            else
                printf("\nArvore Vazia\n\n");
            break;

        case 3:/*excluir folha*/
            if(ptRaiz!=NULL)//se Arvore tem conteudo
            {
                printf("Digite a chave do nodo a ser exclui­do:");
                scanf("%d",&chave);
                excluirFolha(&ptRaiz,chave);
            }
            else
                printf("\nArvore Vazia!\n\n");
            break;

        case 4:/*Procura chave*/
            if(ptRaiz!=NULL)//se Arvore tem conteudo
            {
                printf("Digite a chave do nodo a ser buscado:");
                scanf("%d",&chave);
                procuraChave(ptRaiz,chave);
            }
            else
                printf("\nArvore Vazia!\n\n");
            break;

        case 5: /*Caminhamento pre-fixado*/
            if(ptRaiz!=NULL)//se Arvore tem conteudo
            {
                imprimirPre(ptRaiz);
            }
            else
                printf("\nArvore Vazia!\n\n");
            break;
        case 6:   /*Caminhamento pos-fixado*/
            if(ptRaiz!=NULL)//se Arvore tem conteudo
            {
                imprimirPos(ptRaiz);
            }
            else
                printf("\nArvore Vazia!\n\n");
            break;
        case 7:   /*Caminhamento central*/
            if(ptRaiz!=NULL)//se Arvore tem conteudo
            {
                imprimirCentral(ptRaiz);
            }
            else
                printf("\nArvore Vazia!\n\n");
            break;
        case 8:  /* Verifica se a arvore e AVL */
            if(ptRaiz!=NULL)//se Arvore tem conteudo
            {
                verificaAVL(ptRaiz);
            }
            else
                printf("\nArvore Vazia!\n\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nOpcao Invalida!\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```